# How to filter a date column based on month in MySQL

Tags: mysql, date, where-clause

I'm trying to filter a date column based on month:

```
SELECT  id, nama, lahir_tanggal  
FROM `alumni_db.alumni_tb`   
WHERE date("F", strtotime('lahir_tanggal') = "August";
```

`lahir_tanggal` is in date format

How to make that query work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT id, nama, lahir_tanggal    FROM alumni_db.alumni_tb
 WHERE 
   MONTHNAME(lahir_tanggal) ="August"
```

or

```
SELECT id, nama, lahir_tanggal    FROM alumni_db.alumni_tb
 WHERE 
   MONTH(lahir_tanggal) =8
```

[**SEE HERE**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_monthname)

Comment: SELECT  id, nama, lahir_tanggal  FROM `alumni_tb`   WHERE  (strtotime('lahir_tanggal') = 7);
change to that, still no luck
there is a message

#1305 - FUNCTION alumni_db.strtotime does not exist

Comment: it seems it shoud be something in strtotime, because i have this message

#1054 - Unknown column 'strtotime' in 'where clause'

Comment: what is your date column name

Comment: my date column, is lahir_tanggal

Comment: @PSR.. it worked now, following your suggestion...

SELECT id, nama, lahir_tanggal    
FROM alumni_tb
WHERE 
MONTH(lahir_tanggal ) =8

thankyou

Comment: you need to specify your column name in the braces

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you want to do but I'm assuming you want something like this:

```
SELECT  
    id, nama, lahir_tanggal
FROM 
    `alumni_db.alumni_tb`
WHERE
    MONTH(lahir_tanggal) = 8
```

or

```
SELECT  
    id, nama, lahir_tanggal
FROM 
    `alumni_db.alumni_tb`
WHERE
    MONTHNAME(lahir_tanggal) = 'august'
```

Comment: Yes, it worked now...

    SELECT      id, nama, lahir_tanggal FROM     `alumni_tb` WHERE     MONTH(lahir_tanggal) = 8